# phpmyadmin : cannot enable pagination after show all rows on specific table

Tags: phpmyadmin

phpmyadmin version 4.6.6deb5ubuntu0.5 whith php 7.2.24.

On a specific table phpmyadmin set a huge value for default limit without showing pagination tab. That table contains a lot of records so, every time a choose it, I must wait that browser renders the record list (locking browser most of the time).

This behaviour happens only on a specific table, all other tables are not affected by this problem.

I cannot understand how can I set that behaviour! I look at all available settings but I cannot find  anything, the default value (25 rows with pagination) is still set!

Trying using different PC told me that this setting is not save on cookies or local storage, the problem persist even on different machine.

Comment: Maybe an issue with your table structure

Comment: If you export that table and import it to a different database, does the problem follow?

Comment: If you log in as different user, does the problem still occur? Have you configured the "phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage" (which used to be called pmadb)? A clue would be if you have a `phpmyadmin` database.